# How can i plot this transcendental equation in R?

Tags: r, plot

This is the kepler equation in terms of the angle theta:
`M=2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c)-e*sin(2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c))`
where `e=0.2056` and `c=sqrt((1-e)/(1+e))`

M goes from `0 to 2pi`.
My X value is M and my Y value is theta. What code should I use to plot theta(M)?

Comment: What is the problem? Just generate the range of theta `theta = seq(0,2*pi, 0.1)` and plot it.

Comment: I dont know how to clear theta from that equation ,it is a transcendental equation.i need the theta function to be able to plot it

Comment: It is not the range of theta,it is the range of M,theta is a function and M is the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adjusted answer to make range of M be (0,2*pi)**

Your equation:

> M=2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c)-e*sin(2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c))

defines M as a function of theta. It may be that in actual use you will know M and need to compute theta, but to get a plot,  there is no need for an analytic formula for theta as a function of M.  You just need a series of x-y values. So,  you can generate a sequence of thetas, compute M and plot them, like this:

```
e=0.2056
c=sqrt((1-e)/(1+e))
theta = seq(0,2*pi, 0.1)
M=2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c)-e*sin(2*atan(tan(theta/2)*c)) 
M[M<0] = M[M<0] + 2*pi
plot(M, theta, pch=20)
```

[image: Transcendetal 1]

If you need to be able to compute values of theta from a given M, you can approximate the inverse function like this.

```
THETA = approxfun(M, theta)
plot(M, THETA(M), type="l", ylab="theta")
```

[image: Transcendental 2]

Comment: Thank you so much,that was what i needed,the inverse function of M to get theta

Comment: But, in my case, M has only positive values that go from 0 to 2pi,so i think that the first curve shouldnt appear

Comment: `plot(seq(0.1,pi,0.1), THETA(seq(0.1,pi,0.1)), 
 type="l",  xlab="M", ylab="theta") `

Comment: Thank you,do you know the reason why the curve stops when M is equal to pi,because i wanted the curve to finish at 2*pi not pi?

Comment: Yes. I only gave it data to make the inverse function from -pi to pi. Answer adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the tools to solve complex and non numerical problems we usually face in physics.